# insert duplicate key update for 1000's rows insert in single query

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to insert large volume of rows and it is timing out, how can I make it more efficient/work?

I have tried increasing the timeout, it doesn't help process all the data. The below is an example, there are far more fields of data in real life.

Lets assume reakl life array size is approx 20,000 rows

I looked at adding all the inserts into one statement but it doesn't take care of the **on duplicate update** or least if you can I couldn't figure it out.

ie

```
INSERT INTO table ('a','b','c') values ($v[0]->a,$v[0]->b,$v[0]->c),($v[1]->a,$v[1]->b,$v[1]->c) 

foreach($a as $v){
    $sql.="INSERT INTO table ('a','b','c') values ($v->a,$v->b,$v->c) on duplicate key update a=$v->a, b=$v->b, c=$v->c;"
}

exec($sql);
```

The time taken to process a couple thousand rows is long enough to make nginx/apache/php timeout, which I find odd. but that aside there must be a fast more efficient way to do the above.

`set_time_limit 0` doesnt help

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b = VALUES(b), c = VALUES(c)` will work with a multi-row insert. The MySQL `VALUES` function allows us to access the values that *would have been inserted* if the insert had been successful (not encountered a duplicate key exception) ... `VALUES` function documented here:      https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: the overhead for churning individual statements is non-trivial with large sets, all the work that has to be done by MySQL to parse the SQL text tokens, check for valid syntax, check for valid semantics, does user have privileges, evaluate possible execution plans, executing the plan, obtaining/releasing locks, generating rollback, and the commit... and that's for *every* SQL statement. Processing RBAR (row by agonizing row) can be excruciatingly slow.

Comment: The *fastest* way to insert a bloatload of rows is `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement, but that doesn't support ON DUPLICATE UPDATE, and there's the rigmarole of security, allowing LOCAL INFILE from the client. In some special cases, a `LOAD DATA ... REPLACE` can achieve an equivalent result, but the differences are significant enough that in general it is not equivalent.

Comment: for inserting thousands of rows, in a single statement, beware of the maximum size (limit) on the SQL text, `max_allowed_packet`.  If we insert two rows per insert statement, that's *half* the number of statements. If we do ten rows per insert, that's *one tenth* the number of executions. Once we get to a thousand rows per execution, we've already gained the bulk of performance improvement from reducing the overhead by reducing the number of SQL statement executions. I wouldn't try to do *all* of the rows in a single statement. I'd aim for executing reasonably sized batches.

Comment: thanks Spencer7593 I should have RTM more thoroughly.  I was trying to pass a value into VALUES(a) but 'a' is the col name! much easier and works great.